# What do I need to do to use a MSSQL-Server with Web-Harvester?

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc

Subject nearly says everything. I already downloaded the Microsoft SQL-Server JDBC driver. But how do i use them with web-harvester?
https://sourceforge.net/p/web-harvest/

I Got:

```
<database connection="jdbc:sqlserver://192.168.1.115;databaseName=IMDB;user=sa;password=xxxxxxxxxxxxx ;" jdbcclass="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver">
<template>
INSERT INTO First (imdbid, titel, [plot-kurz], laufzeit)
values (${myId}, '${myUrl}', '${myText}', '${mySource}')
</template>
</database>
```

But with these lines i get:

> org.webharvest.exception.DatabaseException:
>   com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Falsche Syntax in der
>   Nähe von ','. at
>   org.webharvest.runtime.processors.plugins.DatabasePlugin.executePlugin(DatabasePlugin.java:132)
>   at
>   org.webharvest.runtime.processors.WebHarvestPlugin.execute(WebHarvestPlugin.java:125)
>   at
>   org.webharvest.runtime.processors.BaseProcessor.run(BaseProcessor.java:115)
>   at
>   org.webharvest.runtime.processors.BodyProcessor.execute(BodyProcessor.java:25)
>   at
>   org.webharvest.runtime.processors.BaseProcessor.run(BaseProcessor.java:115)
>   at
>   org.webharvest.runtime.processors.CaseProcessor.execute(CaseProcessor.java:68)
>   at
>   org.webharvest.runtime.processors.BaseProcessor.run(BaseProcessor.java:115)
>   at
>   org.webharvest.runtime.processors.BodyProcessor.execute(BodyProcessor.java:25)
>   at
>   org.webharvest.runtime.processors.EmptyProcessor.execute(EmptyProcessor.java:58)
>   at
>   org.webharvest.runtime.processors.BaseProcessor.run(BaseProcessor.java:115)
>   at
>   org.webharvest.runtime.processors.BodyProcessor.execute(BodyProcessor.java:25)
>   at
>   org.webharvest.runtime.processors.BaseProcessor.run(BaseProcessor.java:115)
>   at
>   org.webharvest.runtime.processors.LoopProcessor.execute(LoopProcessor.java:116)
>   at
>   org.webharvest.runtime.processors.BaseProcessor.run(BaseProcessor.java:115)
>   at
>   org.webharvest.runtime.processors.BodyProcessor.execute(BodyProcessor.java:25)
>   at
>   org.webharvest.runtime.processors.WhileProcessor.execute(WhileProcessor.java:94)
>   at
>   org.webharvest.runtime.processors.BaseProcessor.run(BaseProcessor.java:115)
>   at org.webharvest.runtime.Scraper.execute(Scraper.java:166) at
>   org.webharvest.runtime.Scraper.execute(Scraper.java:179) at
>   org.webharvest.gui.ScraperExecutionThread.run(ScraperExecutionThread.java:56)
>   Caused by: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Falsche
>   Syntax in der Nähe von ','. at
>   com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDatabaseError(SQLServerException.java:216)
>   at
>   com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.getNextResult(SQLServerStatement.java:1515)
>   at
>   com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement.doExecutePreparedStatement(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:404)
>   at
>   com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement$PrepStmtExecCmd.doExecute(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:350)
>   at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSCommand.execute(IOBuffer.java:5696)
>   at
>   com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.executeCommand(SQLServerConnection.java:1715)
>   at
>   com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeCommand(SQLServerStatement.java:180)
>   at
>   com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeStatement(SQLServerStatement.java:155)
>   at
>   com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement.execute(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:332)
>   at
>   org.webharvest.runtime.processors.plugins.DatabasePlugin.executePlugin(DatabasePlugin.java:84)
>       ... 19 more

Comment: What have you tried? Might want to start by reading the documentation. I'll be extra nice and even point you to the spot in the documentation that you are interested in: http://web-harvest.sourceforge.net/manual.php#database

Comment: Since the stack trace cites PreparedStatement, I'd suggest leaving off the single quotes.  PreparedStatement is smart enough to escape Strings for you; no need for your code to do it again.  Just INSERT the String value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your connection seems to be working - that error is SQL Server telling you it's getting a bad query. For example: if ${myID} is evaluating as an empty string.

Comment: I just took a look with the SQL Profiler. That was exactly may problem. Thanky you very much :)